# Is meta reputation now separate from the actual site?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have noticed that my meta rep is now different from my Gaming rep.  Does that mean that meta reputation is now separate or is it just a matter of accessing different physical servers and it will just take time to propagate?  Just curious

Comment: It is separate. See: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64/meta-reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is separate -- this is explained in https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/faq

In short, all reputation comes from the parent site.

Comment: Downvoting description of costing rep should be removed from the meta FAQ